# htaccess rewrite rule issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule in my htaccess file like in the following example:

```
     RewriteRule ^company\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/(.+)$ comp_inf.php?cid=$1

     RewriteRule ^company\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/img/(.*)$ ./img/$1 [L]
     RewriteRule ^company\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/css/(.*)$ ./css/$1 [L]
     RewriteRule ^company\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/js/(.*)$  ./js/$1  [L]
```

The url link will look like this:

```
     http://www.example.com/company/1
```

On google search I found duplicate pages that are not defined in the htaccess file

and they're looking like this:

```
     http://www.example.com/company/1/page1.php
     http://www.example.com/company/1/page2.php
```

my question is how to deny the scanning of those pages and why this scanning happening specifically with those two pages.

Thanks in advance.

Ofer.

Comment: Just make the rules more strict by for example only allowing digits. Alternatively change the code of comp_inf.php to return `404 Not Found` for invalid urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should send a [X-Robots noindex,nofollow header](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) with those pages which were accidently being indexed. As soon as the pages are not listed on google anymore ([speed this up](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663427)) you can create a robots.txt with someting like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /company/*/*.php
```

Watch out for non absolute links on http://www.example.com/company/1/ to page1.php or to page2.php - for example:

```
<a href="page1.php">anchortext</a>
```